# How I can find scanned images and camera images dataset for research?

Tags: image, collections, camera, image-scanner

I want to implement an image processing method in order to distinguish scanner images from camera images. How can I collect images from scanners and cameras? The images should be very different in scale and content and capture devices and rgb images or gray-scale images.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most famous database for machine learning is the [**UCI Machine Learning Repository**](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/), where you can find tons of open source datasets organized by learning objective, data type, number of instances and more.

Comment: Anyway you should be more precise on the type of distinction you wan to apply, since to recognize between camera and scanner you can simply look at the meta-data of the picture and see if there is any EXIF file (typically camera images have one embedded).